# Why is `std::array` slower than `std::vector`?

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, vector

**Note: This has only been confirmed in an online IDE, tests on my own laptop do not confirm this.**

Let us test the performance of the two containers with an almost same program, that is calculating the length of first `999999` Collatz sequences. I use `std::array` and `std::vector` in a very similar fashion, to cache first few elements. It turns out that an `std::vector` solution is 3.5 times faster than an `std::array` solution. This is odd for me, since I was told that `std::vector`, being dynamically allocated, will perform slower than a statically allocated array that `std::array` is at its heart.

Is `std::array` inherently slower than `std::vector`? If yes, why? If no, what am I doing wrong in my use of `std::array` and how to fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <ctime>

std::array<std::uint_fast16_t, 999999> cache;

std::uint_fast16_t getCollatzLength(std::uint_fast64_t val) {

    uint_fast16_t excessiveLength = 0;
    while(val > 999999) {
        if(val%2 == 0)
            val /= 2;
        else
            val = 3*val+1;
        ++excessiveLength;
    }

    if(cache[val-1] == 0) {
        if(val%2 == 0)
            cache[val-1] = getCollatzLength(val/2) + 1;
        else
            cache[val-1] = getCollatzLength(3*val+1) + 1;
    }

    return cache[val-1] + excessiveLength;
}

int main()
{
    std::clock_t tStart = std::clock();

    cache.fill(0);
    cache[0] = 1;

    std::uint_fast16_t largest = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 999999; ++i) {
        auto cmax = getCollatzLength(i);
        if(cmax > largest)
            largest = cmax;
    }
    std::cout << largest << '\n';

    std::cout << "Time taken: " << (double)(std::clock() - tStart)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << '\n';
}
```

The above `std::array` solution [runs in 0.067222](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/tT1ZIy9aUYAAROIF)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
#include <ctime>

std::vector<std::uint_fast16_t> cache(999999, 0);

std::uint_fast16_t getCollatzLength(std::uint_fast64_t val) {

    uint_fast16_t excessiveLength = 0;
    while(val > 999999) {
        if(val%2 == 0)
            val /= 2;
        else
            val = 3*val+1;
        ++excessiveLength;
    }

    if(cache[val-1] == 0) {
        if(val%2 == 0)
            cache[val-1] = getCollatzLength(val/2) + 1;
        else
            cache[val-1] = getCollatzLength(3*val+1) + 1;
    }

    return cache[val-1] + excessiveLength;
}

int main()
{
    std::clock_t tStart = std::clock();

    cache[0] = 1;

    std::uint_fast16_t largest = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 999999; ++i) {
        auto cmax = getCollatzLength(i);
        if(cmax > largest)
            largest = cmax;
    }
    std::cout << largest << '\n';

    std::cout << "Time taken: " << (double)(std::clock() - tStart)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << '\n';
}
```

The above `std::vector` solution [runs in 0.0191](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/9YayIIQmPm8I1Hmm)

Comment: Dynamic memory being slower is (usually) only true in terms of the cost of allocating memory from the OS and returning it to the application. Once the memory exists, the cost of reading `vec[i]` and `arr[i]` will differ based only on which one was most recently loaded into cache.

Comment: Running the array test multiple times, the time varies quite significantly. In addition to ~0.6, I saw as low as 0.2.

Comment: What optimisation flags did you specify?

Comment: I am abstracting things, of course; on some hardware, "Dynamic Memory" is an entirely different hardware construct than stack memory, and in those situations, memory accesses might vary greatly. But in conventional situations, my original comment applies.

Comment: For `std::vector`, you are not measuring the time to fill it with 0s, while you are with `std::array`. That might explain the small time difference.

Comment: Your are timing the `array.fill` in the array case, but not in the vector case. Without that, they are pretty equally fast on my machine. Run it a couple of times though, the runtime is to short to tell anything useful from a single measurement with `std::clock`. `std::high_resolution_clock` would have been a better choice here.

Comment: @NeilButterworth As shown in the links, simply `-O3`

Comment: @chris vector test on the other hand, if run multiple times, runs consistently in 0.3-0.2

Comment: (Btw, you don't need to 0 the array in this case, it should be zeroed anyways as a global aggregate.)

Comment: What CPU by the chance? On my Q6600 both versions run almost the same - array version being 0.01 sec faster.

Comment: @BaummitAugen You sure about this? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array says: "*note that default initialization may result in indeterminate values for non-class T*" I can’t use [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), since I’d have to specify all 999999 elts explicitely :( I might be wrong, but as of now I see no other choice than to use `fill`

Comment: @gaazkam Oops, I was wrong about that auto-0, that only works for primitives. You can still use aggregate initialization though. http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/tT1ZIy9aUYAAROIF

Comment: @BaummitAugen I’m still ignorant how, since Your link does not provide an example of this and instead it uses `fill` :)

Comment: Doing benchmarks in an online IDE is not the greatest idea either btw, there are too many unknowns about their system. Like, where is your binary loaded from? What's the system load?

Comment: @Anty Fun, on my Intel Core i5-5200U I was getting pretty steadily ~0.02 for both. Only on melpon wandbox I am getting different results in favor of `std::vector`.

Comment: Gah, copied the wrong link. Here you go: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/sEoj671tIH3WTnfq :)

Comment: Thank you. Still performance results are same ;/  You may be right about this benchmarking on an online IDE, especially since I fail to get similar results on my laptop. Still, it might be interesting why `std::array` pretty steadily tends to be slower there.

Comment: One theory. In the std::array case, the memory is uninitialized (array of base type) and should therefore be stored in the BSS segment.

On modern OS' the BSS segment is generally implemented using COW, with the initial mapping of all memory pages pointing to the OS zero page. When you initialize with fill() you would therefore cause multiple page faults. OTH, std::vector may use memory already mapped to the heap and not need to go through the COW page-fault initialization phase.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Objects with static storage duration are not default-initialized but *zero*-initialized, aren't they, before any other possible (or not) initialization?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Just double checked, seems like you are right.

Answer (score -1):

The thing is that std::array allocates memory statically at compile time, leading to slightly slower compile times.  On the other hand, std::vector uses dynamic heap allocation which makes it faster. It may depend on other factors though

Comment: You are right that this array, being a global variable, is allocated at compile time. But the OP wonders about *run time.*